# JDBC connection issue with wampserver 2.4

Tags: mysql, wampserver

Thank you for giving me you important time. 
I am trying to make a connection between the application and the database using **WampServer 2.4** My configuration file contains settings (root with no password) that correspond to the default MySQL privileged account. My MySQL server is running with this default,
I am using this code to make connection.

```
import java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class implementation {

    public static void main(String[]arg)
    {

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        try
        {
            System.out.println("conneting to Database...");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/db","root","");
            System.out.println("Connection Successful");

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException error)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:" + error.getMessage()); 
        }

        catch(SQLException error)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:" + error.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null) 
                try {
                    connection.close();
                    }
            catch(SQLException ignore)
            {

            }

            if (statement != null) 
                try {
                    statement.close();
                    }

            catch(SQLException ignore)
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

when I am running this code, it doesn't connect me to database. So I tried to get the right port, I checked into **phpinfo()**  and I found this **Hostname:Port**  |  *localhost:0*

So I changed the one line code into this,

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:0/db","root","");
```

when I am running this new line, getting this error.

conneting to Database...

**Error:Communications link failure**

**Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.**

please give me your guidance to sort this out. 
thank you

Comment: Your MySQL server is probably listening on the default port, so you don't need to specify a port in the connection string. Just use `jdbc:mysql://localhost/db`

Comment: thnx @rsanchez, it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your likely error:

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/db","root","");
```

port 80 which you have used on this command is the port the Apache Listens on. MySQL listens on port 3306 by default.

If you have not changed that then you probably dont actually need to put the :xxx port numbr on this cmmand at all.

So try

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db","root","");
```

and see if that works for you

Otherwise try

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","root","");
```

Comment: thnk u so much for ur valuable time, ur answer is really helpful and you sorted out my issue... thanx alot mate.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Frist check on which port Number used is by JDBC and that port number is used by other application or not.

Check your Port Number `80` is used by other application or not, if yes then you have to killed port number 80 or you have to do reconfiguration of JDBC server to run on other port number

check below link :
http://ye5.blogspot.in/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html